# How do I add a Request Model for a POST end point in serverless framework

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

How do I add a Request Model for a POST end point so that it appears in the API Gateway when I then export the API for iOS? I can manually add the request model in AWS, but since this is deployed through server less I need it in there. I see there's a responseModels for defining endpoints, but I can't see a requestModels?

My s-functions.json has this

```
"endpoints": [
    {
      "path": "blog/graphql",
      "method": "POST",
      "type": "AWS",
      "authorizationType": "AWS_IAM",
      "authorizerFunction": false,
      "apiKeyRequired": false,
      "requestParameters": {},
      "requestTemplates": {
        "application/json": "{\"query\" : $input.json(\"$\")}"
      },
      "responses": {
        "400": {
          "statusCode": "400"
        },
        "default": {
          "statusCode": "200",
          "responseParameters": {},
          "responseModels": {},
          "responseTemplates": {},
          "application/json": ""
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

In AWS APIGateway I then need to manually add the request model as

```
{
    "title": "Example Schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "query": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "required": ["query"]
}
```

When I then export the API for iOS I do get the correct method in order to send a graphQL query and it works.

But, since I want to deploy this with the serverless deploy, I can't keep adding this manually.

And I need the API endpoint call to go through the APIGateway SDK fro iOS in order to use the cognito credentials, rather than manually doing a https.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the serverless project's [lib/Endpoint.js](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/blob/master/lib/Endpoint.js) doesn't include an entry for requestModels, but the project is actively maintained so perhaps you can raise an issue on GitHub for them to add support. I thought it might be useful to share an AWS CLI approach to this in the meantime.

You create request models the same way you create response models, but having created them there isn't a simple command equivalent to `aws apigateway put-method-response` to associate request models with the method. This seems a missing feature of AWS CLI.

However, I got it working using `aws apigateway update-method`. You need to have created the model for the request first, and then this command adds it to the method.

```
aws apigateway update-method \
  --region $region \
  --rest-api-id "$rest_api_id" \
  --resource-id "$resource_id" \
  --http-method $method \
  --patch-operations "op=add,path=/requestModels/application~1json,value=${request_model_name}"
```

Note the odd `application~1json` construct is to stop the slash in `application/json` being interpreted as part of the path.

Incidentally I tried and failed to get the JSON file argument to `--patch-operations` working. If anyone can shed any light on why this file leads to the error below I'd love to hear about it.

```
$ cat patch.json
{
    "patchOperations":[{
        "op" : "add",
        "path" : "/requestModels/application~1json",
        "value" : "TestRequest"
    }]
}
$ aws apigateway update-method \
  --rest-api-id abc123 \
  --resource-id def456 \
  --http-method POST \
  --patch-operations "file://patch.json"
Error parsing parameter '--patch-operations': Invalid JSON: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
JSON received: {
```